# How to add callback to method diff.structuredPatch?

Tags: javascript, json, diff

Using library https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff
and calling:

```
function structuredPatch(oldFileName: string, newFileName: string, oldStr: string, newStr: string, 
                         oldHeader: string, newHeader: string, options?: {context: number}): IUniDiff;
```

How do you pass a **callback** to it ?

Comment: You don't, as the docs says: "this function returns an object with an array of hunk objects"

Comment: But below that, the docs also says: _".....All methods above which accept the optional callback method will run in sync mode when that parameter is omitted and in async mode when supplied. This allows for larger diffs without blocking the event loop. This may be passed either directly as the final parameter or as the callback field in the options object. .... "_

Comment: @Danielle "*methods which accept the optional callback*" - `structuredPatch` is no such method.

Comment: You can pass the result to your own callback function

Comment: @Danielle It's admittedly a bit weird since `applyPatches` appears to be the only method with that feature.